# Deserializing to a subclass problems

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have been trying to deserialize some XML into a class which is a subclass of another class. When I tried deserializing into the base class it works. However when the class is deserialized to any of the subclasses it will fail.

I would like to know why this is happening. Is this an OOP design violation or I am just missing out on something. Thanks

Below is the code:

Base Class : Shape.cs

```
namespace Shape
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
    [KnownType(typeof(Rectangle))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Square))]

    public partial class Shape
    {

        private string widthField;

        private string heightField;

        private string colorField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Width
        {
            get
            {
                return this.widthField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.widthField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Height
        {
            get
            {
                return this.heightField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.heightField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.colorField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NewDataSet
    {

        private Shape[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Shape")]
        public Shape[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Subclass #1 : Rectangle.cs

```
namespace Shape
{
    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
    }
}
```

Subclass #2 : Square.cs

```
namespace Shape
{
    public class Square : Shape
    {
    }
}
```

Class which attempts to deserialize XML into Rectangle (Subclass #1)

```
    string xmlSample = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><Shape xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Width>2</Width><Height>5</Height><Color>Red</Color></Shape>";
    //Shape.Shape shape = Utilities.ByteArrayToObject<Shape.Shape>(Utilities.XmlStringToBytes(xmlSample)); <-- Works OK
    Shape.Rectangle rect = Utilities.ByteArrayToObject<Shape.Rectangle>(Utilities.XmlStringToBytes(xmlSample));  //<-- Will fail
```

XSD Schema of Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Shape">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Width" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Height" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="Shape" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find the solution. The fix was to add a [XmlRoot("Shape")] to the subclasses fixed the issue.

Example:

```
[XmlRoot("Shape")]
public class Rectangle : Shape
{ .. }
```

and also same thing for 'Square' class

Answer (score 2):

See code below.  I found a number of issues.  A XML can have only one root node but you had an array of Shape[] as the root.  So I added to your xml NewDataSet.  The names of the objects in the classes didn't match the tags in the xml.  So I added XmlElement to the classes.  I also changed XmlAttribute to XmlElement.  An XmlAttribute has an equal sign in the XML.  You had TEXT in the Xml between the angle brackets.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;


namespace Shape
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlSample = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><NewDataSet xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Shape xsi:type=\"Rectangle\"><Width>2</Width><Height>5</Height><Color>Red</Color></Shape></NewDataSet>";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlSample);

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));
            NewDataSet ds = (NewDataSet)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Rectangle))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Square))]
    [XmlRoot("Shape")]
    public partial class Shape
    {
        private string widthField;
        private string heightField;
        private string colorField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Width")]
        public string Width
        {
            get
            {
                return this.widthField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.widthField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Height")]
        public string Height
        {
            get
            {
                return this.heightField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.heightField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Color")]
        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.colorField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Rectangle")]
    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot("Square")]
    public class Square : Shape
    {
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlRoot("NewDataSet")]
    public partial class NewDataSet
    {

        private Shape[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Shape")]
        public Shape[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }


}
​
```

Comment: Hi @jdweng , seems to be able to deserialize into a 'Shape' class with the above code. But I tried to deserialize into a 'Square' class, and it fails as well. Implictly casted into a Square class : Shape.Square square = (Shape.Square)ds.Items[0];. Error thrown is that 'Unable to cast object of type 'Shape.Shape' to type 'Shape.Square'' Any idea around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

casting to base type is considered safe implicit type conversion in C#.But the reverse is not true.